# Finding the sweetspot for batch inserting

Tags: sql-server

I am inserting 50.000.000 records in a new database in a cursor (if it is of any relevance I am checking wether IP adresses are in a certain range and if they are of the same ISP).

I am using a Nvarchar max to store my query in. I noticed the longer it got the longer the query had to run.

[image: Query time against records used and string length]

This is without querying the data too the database, just creating the string to query.

The string is in the format of

```
INSERT INTO #FOO(x,y) VALUES (1,2),(3,4)
```

So I figured I had to shorten the length of the string and query it in batches (using modulo in a while loop). I decided to query the string for every 50 records.

I noticed this did help, but as there are a lot of records and cannot test what the sweetspot(or close to it) is. I decided to take a sample and see how much time it takes for different amounts of records and different amount of update batches.

[image: Time per batch size]

But it hasn't made me that much wiser. I did notice that the 100 records per batch gets relatively faster the more records it contains. But I cannot confirm this.

I cannot test each case for the 50.000.000 records as it would take too much time. But I do have to rerun the query once in a while to update the database.

Any help would be much appreciated.

If code samples are required, please leave a comment.

Comment: This sort of job seems like it would be better done by generating the full 50 million record set using an app writing to a flat text file, then using DTS to bulk import them.

Comment: @RossPresser I have no experience with this. How can I do this?